# Devstack installation error - Keystone

Tags: openstack, devstack

Managed to work through my errors with DevStack and stack.sh generates about 6900+ logs on the screen so I am guessing I am very close :)

I am using Keystone 3, I manually exported OS_URL, OS_AUTH_URL (in an earlier run it complained about this one) and others. When the script exits, I tried the command manually with the os_url as noted in the logs below but it complains that it doesn't how which plugin to load and when I switch it to v3.0 it complains with a 404.

Following is a snippet of the error from the screen log, wondering if anyone else has seen this:

```
2015-08-26 18:30:38.005 | :./stack.sh:575+echo 'Waiting for keystone to start...'
2015-08-26 18:30:38.005 | Waiting for keystone to start...
2015-08-26 18:30:38.005 | :./stack.sh:579+wait_for_service 60 http://172.16.11.14:5000/v2.0/
2015-08-26 18:30:38.005 | :./stack.sh:340+local timeout=60
2015-08-26 18:30:38.005 | :./stack.sh:341+local url=http://172.16.11.14:5000/v2.0/
2015-08-26 18:30:38.005 | :./stack.sh:342+timeout 60 sh -c 'while ! curl -g -k --noproxy '\''*'\'' -s http://172.16.11.14:5000/v2.0/ >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done'
2015-08-26 18:30:38.591 | :./stack.sh:584+is_service_enabled tls-proxy
2015-08-26 18:30:38.593 | :./stack.sh:1738+return 1
2015-08-26 18:30:38.593 | :./stack.sh:976+SERVICE_ENDPOINT=http://172.16.11.14:35357/v2.0
2015-08-26 18:30:38.593 | :./stack.sh:978+is_service_enabled tls-proxy
2015-08-26 18:30:38.596 | :./stack.sh:1738+return 1
2015-08-26 18:30:38.596 | :./stack.sh:985+export OS_TOKEN=password
2015-08-26 18:30:38.596 | :./stack.sh:985+OS_TOKEN=password
2015-08-26 18:30:38.597 | :./stack.sh:986+export OS_URL=http://172.16.11.14:35357/v2.0
2015-08-26 18:30:38.597 | :./stack.sh:986+OS_URL=http://172.16.11.14:35357/v2.0
2015-08-26 18:30:38.597 | :./stack.sh:988+create_keystone_accounts
2015-08-26 18:30:38.597 | ::./stack.sh:376+get_or_create_project admin
2015-08-26 18:30:38.597 | ::./stack.sh:729+local os_cmd=openstack
2015-08-26 18:30:38.597 | ::./stack.sh:730+local domain=
2015-08-26 18:30:38.597 | ::./stack.sh:731+[[ ! -z '' ]]
2015-08-26 18:30:38.597 | :::./stack.sh:740+openstack project create admin --or-show -f value -c id
2015-08-26 18:30:39.596 | ERROR: openstack The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404) (Request-ID: req-a5703c0a-bdb4-4ca0-8bf7-61ddbacbddf1)
2015-08-26 18:30:39.617 | ::./stack.sh:738+local project_id=
2015-08-26 18:30:39.617 | ::./stack.sh:739+echo
2015-08-26 18:30:39.617 | :./stack.sh:376+local admin_tenant=
2015-08-26 18:30:39.617 | ::./stack.sh:377+get_or_create_user admin password
2015-08-26 18:30:39.618 | ::./stack.sh:700+[[ ! -z '' ]]
2015-08-26 18:30:39.618 | ::./stack.sh:703+local email=
2015-08-26 18:30:39.618 | ::./stack.sh:705+local os_cmd=openstack
2015-08-26 18:30:39.618 | ::./stack.sh:706+local domain=
2015-08-26 18:30:39.618 | ::./stack.sh:707+[[ ! -z '' ]]
2015-08-26 18:30:39.618 | :::./stack.sh:723+openstack user create admin --password password --or-show -f value -c id
2015-08-26 18:30:40.853 | ERROR: openstack 'links'
```

Answer (score 0):

On inspecting the logs across many files, I found that --os-url was getting a null value and hence the 404. To fix this I added OS_URL to openrc file (export OS_URL=http://:5000.... )

I then also had to force use of the identity v3 ... for this you need to modify the get_or_add_project_role sub-routine in the functions-common file (should be around line 775...) to specify the --os-url=$KEYSTONE_SERVICE_URI_V3 and --os-identity-api-version=3 options.

I was then able to get past this error.

Hope that helps.